# Best Anitivirus for vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd, bitdefender

I have implemented VSFTPD in one of my project server. I would like to scan the files before placing it in the respective directory. Can you please suggest some Antivirus for scanning the files. Can i use bit defender Scanner for scanning the files?

Comment: You can use whatever anti virus you believe to work best. Unfortunately we can't recommend any particular anti virus brand as it is out of scope and will be primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you indeed CAN use Bitdefender on your Linux server - https://www.bitdefender.com/business/security.html - though I assume you are using this server for business purposes and are willing to pay the $110+ a year for the license? The above link is to the "newest flavor" of business-class Bitdefender of "Linuxes"/Unicies but there seems to be some dying gasps left of the older product that may still be available to "sample". I would suggest you read over the article (and skip the market-y parts towards the bottom) - https://www.pcsteps.com/6528-linux-virus-scan/

If you are not ready to make that investment or don't want to mess with any free trials / temporary licenses: 
There seems to be an abundance of Linux folks that have been extremely satisfied with the results of ClamAV + clamscan (utility) for the better part of a decade (and even longer). Probably because its open source and broadly used across different flavors of OSes. - https://www.clamav.net/

There are a considerable amount of antivirus products that use ClamAV virus definitions, but "package" the virus utility functionality in a slightly different (oft more targeted or convenient) way. eg. Comodo's Immunet Antivirus utility for Windows. It's pretty solid, tried and true; though there is no such thing as a "perfect" anti-virus solution (eg. Zero-day).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV
It appears, with a bit of command line and config file magic, you could write a cron job (or perhaps a BASH script on a upload "trigger"?) that could scan the files once they are uploaded. VSFTPD seems to be losing favor to a little more "full featured" and user friendly flavors of FTP (eg. PureFTPD) but its still a solid option, regardless.

I've mostly used VSFTPD in the past and used "less instant" methods of virus scanning, though it's rare these days that I use a public-facing FTP server that allows "guest account" uploads. It's generally good practice to force the end user to provide some details about themselves before allowing file uploads. Forcing some sort of account upon them also provides a more simplified means to limit the bandwidth consumption as well. Virus protection, in cases such as these where the end-user has an account, is then mostly for the added security of protecting your server and other users who share files from spreading viruses they do not know that they have.

If it were me doing whatever it is you are doing to worry enough about instantaneous virus scanning on uploaded ftp files, I'd go with a cron triggered virus scan on the user upload directory that is properly secured with secure chmod settings and gets moved over to a "safe space" as long as the virus scan comes up clean. Pseudo coded, something like:

```
do
 *scan the file*
 if [ $scanresult = "clean" ]; then
 echo "yes! The file is cool."
 mv /sketchyuploads/username/thefile /safeuploads/username/thefile
else
 echo "no! Virus! exterminate!"
 rm -f /sketchyuploads/username/thefile
fi
done
```

NOTE: THIS IS ONLY PSEUDO CODE FOR A POSSIBLE BASH SCRIPT, DO NOT THINK THIS WILL WORK AS IS. But you should get the idea from that. You could maybe trigger a cron job to fire from the successful upload (prefered) or 'poll' the upload directory for changes / new files on an interval maybe (resource intensive, but a possible option for a very busy dedicated ftp server)? These are just suggestions.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Kanidirve for your valuable response. I will check and implement any of the two solutions suggested by you based on my project requirement .